# Using multithreading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am doing address string match using python fuzzywuzzy library and also parallelising it using multiprocessing module. Here is my current code,

```
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing import Pool
test = pd.DataFrame({'Address1':['123 Cheese Way','234 Cookie Place','345 Pizza Drive','456 Pretzel Junction'],'city':['X','U','X','U']}) 
test2 = pd.DataFrame({'Address1':['123 chese wy','234 kookie Pl','345 Pizzza DR','456 Pretzel Junktion'],'city':['X','U','Z','Y'] , 'ID' : ['1','3','4','8']})

test=test.assign(dataset = 'test')
test2=test2.assign(dataset = 'test2')

newdf=pd.concat([test2,test],keys = ['test2','test'])
gpd=newdf.groupby('city')

def my_func(mygrp):
    test_data=mygrp.loc['test']
    test2_data=mygrp.loc['test2']
    test2_data = test2_data.loc[:,['ID','Address1']].set_index('ID') 
    del test2_data.index.name 
    other = {x.Index : x.Address1 for x in test2_data.itertuples()}
    test_data['applied']=test_data['Address1'].apply(lambda x: process.extract(x, other , limit = 1))
    return test_data

mypool=Pool(processes=2)
ret_list=mypool.imap(my_func,(group for name, group in gpd))
result = pd.concat(ret_list, axis=0)
```

This is working fine. Its working on a big dataset (test and test2 each has more than 3 million records). So utilising an ec2 instance with more processing power - 64GB, however we are now moving to a smaller instance with 32GB, so trying to may be rewrite this in multithreading if possible. From what i read so far, it seems multithreading CPU bound tasks in python is not feasible due to GIL. Any suggestions on this? Is there any other possible solution to speed up this task?

Or is it possible to do this string match using word2vec ?

Comment: Have a look at Cython or PyPy if you need to improve performance of python code.

Comment: Thanks. How can i use them just for this script when i am running all my other python scripts currently in anaconda env?

Comment: Have you considered using [dask](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/)?

Comment: Code using `multiprocessing` is not affected by the GIL. It only affects `threading`. As long as the processes does not need to communicate/be synchronized (too often) `multiprocessing` can be used as a replacement for `threading` for CPU bound tasks in Python.